# window.addEventListener in javascript doesn't trigger on Chrome pages starting with "chrome://"

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to write a chrome extension for my personal use, which should detect pressing a specific combination of keys, using the function `window.addEventListener`. However, it doesn't trigger on pages starting with "`chrome://`", like "`chrome://extensions`". That's an issue for me because actually the only use of this key presses detection is inside another specific chrome extension that I use regularly.
Can this be overcome?

Comment: Try `document.addEventListener()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `chrome://*` scheme isn't a permitted scheme for injecting a content script.

> A match pattern is essentially a URL that begins with a permitted scheme (http, https, file, or ftp, and that can contain '*' characters.  [*](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns)

If you're wanting to hook into the functionality of an existing extension, the only available option is to modify the extension to do what you need it to to do and re-load it.

If you're lucky, the source is available in some repo for you to modify.

It's more likely that you'll have to modify the extension that was installed from the store.   To do this,  you'll have to track down where it's installed by searching your computer for the extension id and creating a new extension from the contents of the extension folder.   You most likely won't be able to edit it in place because it's signed.